# How to append text to comment in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that appends text to any cell's comment, however it removes all comment formatting.

My current code is as simple as

```
c.Comment.text "something to append" & " " & c.Comment.text
```

Is it possible to do this job, but without losing all comment's formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented, the `Text` method [has three parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff822375.aspx).
Use all three to keep existing text:

```
c.Comment.Text "something to append ", 1, False
```

Comment: I'm kinda new to Visual Basic in Excel and should read the documentation more carefully. Thank you very much.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It prepends text instead of appending it.

Comment: @Expenzor And that is exactly what the OP meant when they said "append", which is easy to see from the code they used where `"something to append"` is in the beginning. They did not use it in the [append vs prepend fashion](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79323/524), but in the "add vs replace" sense. If you want it to be in the end, adjust the second parameter accordingly.

Comment: Oh well. Technically not the answer to the question if someone else is looking. I tried len(.Comment.Text) but it doesn't return the proper length. Text gets appended in between the previously existing Text :/

Comment: @Expenzor Is that because you did not add `1` to `len(.Comment.Text)`, so it got inserted before the last character?

Comment: Wow. That makes a lot of sense. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful when using the Characters functions because there are ancient bugs in Excel and I have found that this can cause instability and unreproduceable crashes if used with large workbook.