# How to add comment in VBA when it already exists?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to add comment into a cell when a comment is already there? I would need do add the text to existing comment. I tried below but it does not work...
Indexes since this is a part of a loop.
Can someone help how could it be done easily?
Thanks a lot :)

```
                koment2 = Worksheets("x").Cells(n - 1, s).Comment.Text & koment2 & Chr(10) & Worksheets("y").Cells(i, 1) & " "
                Worksheets("x").Cells(n - 1, s).ClearComments
                Worksheets("x").Cells(n - 1, s).AddComment (koment2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append text to comment in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696807/how-to-append-text-to-comment-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to add comment to existing cell having a comment.

```vb
Range("A1").Comment.Text (Range("A1").Comment.Text & "New Edited Comment.")
```

In your case it will be

```vb
Worksheets("x").Cells(n - 1, s).Comment.Text (Worksheets("x").Cells(n - 1, s).Comment.Text & "New Edited Comment.")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it but this does not work, following error appears: Runtime Error ´91´, Object variable or With variable not set

Comment: This error indicates that the object doesn't exist or isn't found at the indicated range: 1) fully qualify your range reference via the sheet's CodeName (e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1")`) or by prefixing e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x")` and 2) test via e.g. `If Not Sheet1.Comment Is Nothing Then` whether the comment exists yet, `Else` execute e.g. `Sheet1.AddComment "New Comment"`

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote and mark this as answer if it has helped you.